# How to create HDFS for a text file in Apache Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

This is the first time I deal with big data and use cluster.

In order to distribute the bytes among the slaves nodes I read that it is easy to use the HDFS with Apache spark.

How to create HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Spark to process files even without HDFS if you just want to experiment and learn. Take a look at the [Spark Quick Start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html).

If you do need an HDFS cluster, your best bet is installing one of the big Hadoop distributions. [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads.html), [Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/downloads/#data-platform), [MapR](https://www.mapr.com/get-started-with-mapr) all provide easy and free installers and paid support services.

Comment: I already installed spark on the top of Hadoop.now I want to create HDFS so when I read from the files I have I just write the link "HDFS: file name" . How?

Comment: If Spark is running on Hadoop, you can just refer to files as `/data.csv` and that will look for the file in the HDFS root.

Comment: But the file is a text file not a csv one

Comment: What difference does that make? Refer to it as `/data.txt` then. If you're not sure what a file is, please open a separate question for that. Thanks!